# KendoUI Grid with dropdownlist gets progressively slower when making selections

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a KendoUI Grid and for some of the columns you can click and select a value from a dropdown list menu.

The problem is, if I add a few new rows to my grid and start selecting options from the dropdowns for any given column the selection speed seems to slow down exponentially.

E.g. If I add four rows and select something for a column in the first row the speed is fine.
If I then select something from one of the dropdowns in row two it is a little slower.
Then if I select something for row three or four it is ridiculously slow.

I have checked out everything in inspector, memory usage is fine and there are no huge ajax requests. The only thing I see when looking in task manager is that CPU usage goes to 100% until the selection unfreezes.

Here is one of my dropdowns (they are all pretty much identical):

```
function conditionDropdown(container, options)
{
  $('<input required data-text-field="conditionName" data-value-field="conditionId" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
  .appendTo(container)
  .kendoDropDownList({
    autoBind: false,
    dataSource: [{
      conditionName: "Used", 
      conditionId: 2
    }, {
      conditionName: "New", 
      conditionId: 1
    }]
  })
}
```

And my KendoUI Grid:

```
$('#partsGrid').kendoGrid({
      dataSource: {
        data: partData,
        pageSize: 10,
        autoSync: true,
        schema: {
          model: {
            fields: {
              id: {
                type: "number",
                editable: false
              },
              quantity: {
                type: "number",
              },
              partNumber: {
                type: "string",
              },
              manufacturer: {
                type: "string",
              },
              partTypes: {
                defaultValue: {
                  partTypeId: 1, 
                  partType: "Unknown"
                }
              },
              jobTypes: {
                defaultValue: {
                  jobTypeId: 2, 
                  jobType: "Supply"
                }
              },
              conditions: {
                defaultValue: {
                  conditionId: 1, 
                  conditionName: "New"
                }
              },
              urgency: {
                defaultValue: {
                  urgencyId: 3, 
                  urgencyName: "Standard"
                }
              },
              leadtimes: {
                defaultValue: {
                  leadtimeId: 3, 
                  leadtimeName: "Standard"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      columns: [
      {
        field: 'quantity',
        width: 40,
        title: 'Qty',
      },
      {
        field: 'partNumber',
        width: 120,
        title: 'Part number',
        editor: partNumberScanner
      },
      {
        field: 'manufacturer',
        width: 120,
        title: 'Manufacturer',
      },
      {
        field: 'partTypes',
        width: 80,
        title: 'Part type',
        editor: partTypeDropdown,
        template: "#=partTypes.partType#"
      },
      {
        field: 'jobTypes',
        width: 80,
        title: 'Job type',
        editor: jobTypeDropdown,
        template: "#=jobTypes.jobType#"
      },
      {
        field: 'conditions',
        width: 70,
        title: 'Condition',
        editor: conditionDropdown,
        template: "#=conditions.conditionName#"
      },
      {
        field: 'urgency',
        width: 100,
        title: 'Urgency',
        editor: urgencyDropdown,
        template: "#=urgency.urgencyName#"
      },
      {
        field: 'leadtimes',
        width: 100,
        title: 'Lead time',
        editor: leadtimeDropdown,
        template: "#=leadtimes.leadtimeName#"
      }
      ],
      editable: {
        update: true,
        destroy: true,
        confirmation: false
      },
      toolbar: [
      {
        name: "create", 
        text: "Add part",
        className:"k-grid-insert-expense"
      }
      ]
    })
    $(".k-grid-insert-expense").bind("click", function (ev) {
      grid.addRow();
    });
    grid = $('#partsGrid').data("kendoGrid");

    grid.dataSource.bind("sync", function(e) {
      parts = grid.dataSource.data();
      partData = parts;
      grid.dataSource.success(parts);
    });
```

---

If I change `autoSync` to false in my grid `dataSource` all speed problems resolve, however this breaks several of my desired behaviours.

---

After more testing it seems to be this line causing the slow down:

```
grid.dataSource.success(parts);
```

Anyone know why?